# Excel 2013 complex countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a source sheet set up like this:

```
 Days Open     Month
 10             1
 4              1
 6              1
 2              1
 4              2
 2              2
 -1             2
 4              3
 6              3
 7              4
 3              4
```

etc

I'm trying to set up a formula to count rows based on the following criteria:

cells in Days Open column <=5 and <>-1 where the month is either 2, 3, or 4 (the worksheet will eventually have month numbers up to 12, and I need to group results quarterly). The total must then be divided by the total of ALL rows in which 2, 3, or 4 appears in the Month column.

I can't seem to get the first part of the COUNTIFS to work with both criteria... this is what I have so far that I'm trying to make work:

`=COUNTIFS('Cumulative Complaints'!K:K,"<=5",'Cumulative Complaints'!K:K,"<>-1")/(COUNTIF('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L,"2")+COUNTIF('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L,"3")+COUNTIF('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L,"4"))`

I've been looking around here and other excel forums and think maybe `SUMPRODUCT` is the way to go? I haven't been able to get that to work though, given the criteria needed on the Days Open column (<=5 and <>-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping a [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) or [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) function in a [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) allows you to use an array of constants as **OR** citeria.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Cumulative Complaints'!K:K, "<>"&-1,'Cumulative Complaints'!K:K, "<="&5,'Cumulative Complaints'!L:L, {2,3,4}))/SUM(COUNTIF('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L, {2,3,4}))
```

This is not an array formula and does not require CSE.

Answer (score 3):

Try this SUMPRODUCT() FORMULA:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Cumulative Complaints'!K:K<=5)*('Cumulative Complaints'!K:K<>-1)*('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L>=2)*('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L<=4))/SUMPRODUCT(('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L>=2)*('Cumulative Complaints'!L:L<=4))
```

When using the SUMPRODUCT the condition `AND` is replaced with the `*`.  It requires all four conditions to be True to return a 1; 1*1*1*1 = 1 if any are false they return 0 so 1*1*0*1 = 0.  So as it iterates through the rows it returns a 1 or a 0 to the be added to the sum.

Comment: Sorry to keep picking up on this, but I really can't emphasize enough how bad an idea it is to reference entire columns within SUMPRODUCT. Although such a practice has no detriment when using COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), this is not all the case with SUMPRODUCT (or any other array-processing function). Unless the OP genuinely has data extending all the way to row one million-plus, you are asking Excel to check potentially hundreds of thousands more cells than are actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be to take a different approach.

Excel has a very powerful feature called Pivot Tables, and I think it might be a good fit for your problem and other similar problems you may face.

First, I would add a couple columns to your table, like so:

```
Days Open   Month   Quarter RecentlyOpened
    10          1       1       FALSE
    4           1       1       TRUE
    6           1       1       FALSE
    2           1       1       TRUE
    4           2       1       TRUE
    2           2       1       TRUE
    -1          2       1       FALSE
    4           3       1       TRUE
    6           3       1       FALSE
    7           4       2       FALSE
    3           4       2       TRUE
```

- The formula for Quarter is: `=CEILING(B2/3,1)`
- The formula for RecentlyOpened is: `=AND(A2<>-1,A2<=5)`

Second, select the table, and do Insert > Pivot Table.

Third, drag from the fields to the boxes, like so:

- Drag Quarter to the ROWS box
- Drag RecentlyOpened to the FILTERS box
- Drag Month to the VALUES box

Fourth, click Sum of Month, and select Value Field Settings to change Sum to Count.

Fifth, set the RecentlyOpened filter to TRUE.

The result is this:

[image]

Pivot Tables often provide a solution that is more flexible and easier to read and understand versus complex formulas.

Comment: I like your pivot table solution, it is more elegant... however because of the way this workbook is formatted I needed the % result in a cell I can reference somewhere else. Thanks!

Comment: The cells of the pivot table can be accessed just like any cell. So, you could refer to B4 in the pivot table from another worksheet, or you could write a formula like `=Sheet2!B4/Sheet2!B6` to get the percentage you are looking for.